# Alguna idea de como hacer el submit del boton usan javascript o jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5

Aquí envío los datos pero debo presionar el botón y quiero hacerlo que
tambien se pueda al presionar enter:

```
<input type="text" name="fecha" id="fecha">
<input type="text" name="direccion" id="direccion">
<div id="enviar">Enviar</div>
```

acá se reciben en jquery:

```
 $("#enviar").click(function(){

    fecha =$("#fecha").val();
    direccion =$("#direccion").val();


    });
```

Comment: ponle al boton la propiedad type="submit", y el Jquery pon el evento submit al formulario tal que haci: `$('FormID').submit(function () { /* Insert Code */ })`

Comment: no funciono no es un buttom es un div el que activa el evento pero solo lo hace por click como hago para que lo haga por click y por submit

Comment: por qué no un form? siempre podes interceptar el submit

Comment: el form si lo uso lo uso, el problema esta es en que tengo un evento onclick solo se activara si clickeo el boton, pero tambien quiero que se pueda al hacer un submit con la funcion de jquery

Comment: un enter en un input dentro de un form envia el form, salvo que le digas que no lo haga (el form tiene que tener un action, en algunos navegadores necesitas un elemento type submit)

Comment: No termino de entender qué es lo que quieres. ¿Quieres que se envíe el formulario al presionar el botón o al presionar enter? ¿Al presionar enter dónde?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
   $(document).bind('keypress', function(e) {
    if(e.keyCode==13){
        $('#enviar').trigger('click');
    }
});

 $("#enviar").click(function(){
    fecha =$("#fecha").val();
    direccion =$("#direccion").val();


});
```